# Resistor colour code chart

Tags: resistors

China has recently changed the colour code for resistors.I searched on google but it didn't show the real value of the Chinese 4 band resistor.Please help!!!

Comment: **[citation needed]**

Comment: Maybe you just have a batch of rubber resistors?

Comment: Sometimes the manufacturers run out of (say) green ink and they might substitute a similar color such as orange or purple. You can just measure each one.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany How are orange or purple similar to green?

Comment: @Majenko Sometimes I think attempts at humor do not communicate well in this medium.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany I have often thought that too.  I can relate green and orange together - they are both colours of bug blood in Starship Troopers. Not sure about purple though - I don't recall seeing any purple blood in it...

Comment: @Majenko Technically, it's [hemolymph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hemolymph), not blood. Please try to be more accurate in your description of alien biology in the future.

Comment: @PhilFrost You're assuming alien bugs have the same biological structure as bugs on Earth. Hemolymph is neither orange nor green (normally) so it can't be that.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany The medium doesn't seem to be as unsmiling as the site. :-(

Comment: @EMFields They are just getting in shape for a new year of confusing, bludgeoning and abusing newcomers to make them feel unwelcome and prone to leave. The boys started the ball rolling with a bit of harmlessless* banter and NA has kicked in behind in not understanding (according to the std message) what is being asked. Looking good, or, at least, predictable, for the new year. [[* no, I didn't stutter].[SP at least then added a useful answer - +1]

Comment: @RussellMcMahon I like Spehro. He's usually right on the money, and when he's apprised that he's off a little he doesn't make a big deal out of trying to kill the messenger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More seriously, are you sure you don't have a 5-band resistor (typically used for 1% and better resistors) and you're comparing it to a 4-band code? Or vice-versa?

Color/colour codes are pretty much dead in 2014-5- they're still used on legacy through-hole and MELF resistors and some through-hole and MELF capacitors, and some diodes, but newer (as in the last decade or two) SMT parts tend to be marked either with a numeric code or the newer alphanumeric code, and the smallest parts, unfortunately, are no longer marked at all. Edit: also axial lead inductors still have color codes.

Comment: Don't forget some tth inductors ... anyways on 0.25 mm x 0.125 mm smt parts reliable readable marking would probably cost ten times as much...

Comment: I can't get you. I have a resistor with the colour code brown-black-red. The shopkeeper told me it is 10k but according to the chart it is 20k. Even     according to one chart it was 1k

Comment: Brown-black-red is 1K.  Red-black-brown would be 200 ohms.  Measure the things with an ohmmeter to be sure...  (brown-black-orange would be 10K)

Comment: That one was my sight mistake i thought it is red. But one of my resistor  be 51k but according to the chart it is 56k. The color code is green-blue-orange-gold.

Comment: @Yash 56k to 56k does not indicate a change in code - it probably indicates a combination of errors in resistor fabrication and meter (and possibly user). Grn-Blu-Org is a std E12 value of 56k as you say. Measuring a range of resistors from the same source and comparing actual and apparent values would give an indication of what sort of tolerance you can expect between actual and measured values.